# Is it possible to change password on the phone itself for gmail/market/other google apps?

Tags: password, google-account

I think this is a general question that would apply to all Android phones though I have a HTC Desire Z.

I cannot find a section on any of the settings to change the password for the Google account used for gmail, Android Market or any of the other google account dependent services and features on the phone. Surely this is a glaring omission?

I would expect a feature to be present *on the phone* and for extra security, have it ask me for the existing password in order to allow me to change to a new one.

Obviously I can change the password when logged into Google in a browser on a PC/Mac but this is an unnecessary procedure - surely we are all becoming increasingly mobile-centric, so shouldn't it be possible to change it *on the phone*?

I have searched here and on Google, the only answers I can find are things like:

- people who need to enter the new password on the phone after changing it to this new password when on a PC or Mac logged into Google on a browser for example.
- people who want to change their actual google account, i.e. use a different one

But I can't find anything about a section on the phone itself to change the password for Gmail,Android Market and other google account dependent services and features on the phone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a perfect solution but you can change your password by opening you Google account/Gmail on your phone browser.

Comment: yes true - this is definitely a possibility if you use Dolphin browser Agent set to Desktop to access gmail.

Comment: I can from my regular Android browser as well. I can click "Desktop" at the bottom to request desktop version of the site or in ICS I can click menu to request desktop version of the site.

Comment: Accepted answer. I can work with this and @Richard Borcsik's comments are worth bearing in mind too.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible at this time.

Should it be?  I think so but like a lot of features that ***I*** think Google ***should*** implement, they don't necessarily agree.

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED,  was driving me nuts, this works folks

The following is only applicable when:

- A Gmail account has been previously set up on the device
- The account password has been subsequently changed via the Gmail or Google website.

From the Home screen, swipe down on the status bar.

- Tap Account Action Required.
- From the 'Couldn't sign in' screen, tap Try Again.
- Note To switch Gmail accounts, tap the Dropdown menu (located in the upper-left) then select the account.
- From the 'Re-type password' screen and enter the appropriate password then tap Next (located in the lower-right).