# Recover password with phone logged in? Need to set up additional device

Tags: google-account, password, multiple-devices

I bought a new android tablet but I can't remember my google acoount password. 
I can't reset it because my phone is already logged in. It says I need to be logged off for 4 days.
Is there a way to just get my password?
Since the phone is already logged in, is there a way to change security settings through the phone account without havng to enter the password?

Comment: What's wersion of Android do you use?

Comment: You might want to check: [Recover Google account password without unlinking/deleting the main account from android device](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/16575), [Is it possible to change password on the phone itself for gmail/market/other google apps?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26291/16575), and [How do I change the password of my main Google account on a Droid X?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12952/16575)