# Recover Google account password without unlinking/deleting the main account from android device

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, google-account, 4.2-jelly-bean, password

I forgot the password for my Google account and I want to recover it. This Google account happens to be the main Google account linked to my Android device.

When I try to use the [Recovery options](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/recoveryoptions):

- A password reset link can only be sent if you haven't signed in for 4 days.
- Your security question can only be answered if you haven't signed in for 5 days.
- A third option where "I no longer have access to those above", it implies a very long password recovery process and **MAY** get the password again.

If I don't unlink this Google account from Android device, the device will continue to sign in to Google services. So, recovery options can't be used.

I don't want to reset my phone to unlink/delete the main Google account, wait 4-5 days and then get the password. This means I can't use my phone for this amount of time and may lose data.

How to get it without unlinking or deleting the Google account of my Google Nexus with Android 4.2.1 (Jelly Bean)?

Comment: I assume that you just created your Google account today, or 4-5 days ago? Is that correct?

Comment: @geff No. Its not correct. If he doesn't unlink Google account from Android device, the device will continue to sign in to Google services. So, recovery options can't be used.

Comment: I have had reset links sent to me even though I logged in yesterday...

Comment: @geff no, it is not correct. I created it about a year I guess. The amount of days which is shown in the recovery options also is different on every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to receive reset links despite having logged in today, yesterday and pretty much every day. However you should be able to access your account on your phone (as it will use your login details to sign in to chrome) then use that to add your phone number to your account. Then pick reset my password with my phone which will send an SMS to your phone.

Comment: I end up with this: Started browser at my phone and requested www.google.com. Then I was asked, if I want to login into my google account using the google account login information that is stored on my phone. I touched "yes". After that I moved to https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery and there I was able to use the password reset link!

Comment: @ЮнгвиртТони Unfortunately this didn't work for me: It asked me to specify username/password to log in. Stupid thing with the "forgot my password" procedure: I get asked for the last pwd I remember (mandatory field). It's my wife's tab set up 2 years ago, I do not remember any pwd -- so no way to continue from there :(

Comment: @Izzy Which Android version do you run?

Comment: @ЮнгвиртТони On the device in question: 2.1 (yeah, out-of-service, a >2 year old tabby).